# Status of going out of beta?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago I read here (will add link when I find it) that we were close to leaving beta. I have not heard anything about it since.

Do we have a date for leaving beta? If not, do we still know what needs to happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, thank you all so much for your patience with us right now. We've been completely swamped by various design and dev requests, and various and sundry things have been pushed down The Big List by necessity more than desire. None of us *wants* to have to put off fulfilling a site's design, but unfortunately things come up.

A lot of this post is going to echo [what I said over at Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5272/why-many-features-and-bug-reports-are-pending-for-years-without-being-implemente/5276#5276), about the delays in bug and feature request resolution. That's because the explanations are similar.

Our development team is ~7 people, and our design team consists of a single soul, the excellent [Jin](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/9/jin). Jin has had several project come up that have required more immediate attention than he could give to your site. It's unfortunate, but it's also the truth. Jin is overextended as is, given that he runs design for *all* of our products: Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, some Careers 2.0 work, as well as some advertising and one-off promotional work. Jin also helps us design and implement the work for things like [Apptivate.ms](http://apptivate.ms/) and some other promo-type events.

We have a lot of design demands. It's part and parcel of why [**we're hiring for a lot of positions**](http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring), including a couple of designers. Until then, though, we ask for your continued patience.

We've slated you to receive a design. That part hasn't and likely will not change. We just...need you to sit tight and keep on being awesome and amazing. I wish I had more news for you, but you *are* in the queue for it. It's on The Big List, and it *will* happen. Just...give us 6-8 weeks. :)

Comment: Thanks Aarthi. I think I speak for more people here when I say we are just really grateful to have a site at all - a cool design would just be a wonderful bonus!

Comment: +1... of course, I couldn't resist the final 4 words :D

Comment: 6-8 weeks from the end of November is mid-to-end of January. Is there any further news?

Comment: @AndrewLeach We just launched [Travel.se] and you're all next on the list. :)

Answer (score 6):

Yep, [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6182596#6182596) is where Jin said that we were ready to graduate. He also said that there was one site ahead of us in the graphic design process, so Jin would finish that site first and then start on ours. The majority of the chat over the next few days is stuff about how the site will look.

Later, on November 2, waxeagle [figured out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6742476#6742476) that the one site before us was most likely Travel.SE. They were told that they would graduate soon...back in July. As of November 25, [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) still has the Beta theme, so Jin's not done with them yet.

In short, we're ready to graduate, but we probably won't for another six to eight weeks.

Comment: for those unfamiliar with the meme 6-8 weeks is SEI for sometime in the nearish future.

Comment: Thanks, but this raises more questions than it answers. Have no sites graduated since July? What's going on at SE?

Comment: @Wikis Sites graduate when they're ready. There is no particular schedule as such. We're looking for more designers right now to make things easier on Jin and to speed up these graduations, but until we find some... things are gonna be a bit delayed.

Comment: @AnnaLear: thanks. Am I to understand that this site is *not* ready from your reply? Or are we just waiting for a design?

Comment: @Wikis You're just waiting for a design.

Comment: @AnnaLear: good to hear, thanks.

Comment: Correction to what @waxeagle said: "six to eight weeks" means "sometime".  Or "whenever".  It doesn't imply "never", it really means it *will* happen.   Just when is anyone's guess. ;-)  (So, "nearish future" is not wrong... for potentially very large values of "nearish" ;-)